# Check in single file with Mercurial?

Tags: version-control, mercurial, dvcs

Let's say you do `hg status` and you have three files modified.  I know how to check in all three files (`hg commit`).  But how can you check in (and then `hg push`) just *one* of the modified files?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using mercurial, what's the easiest way to commit and push a single file while leaving other modifications alone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/125272/using-mercurial-whats-the-easiest-way-to-commit-and-push-a-single-file-while-le)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Please check [the output of `hg help commit`](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#commit) which reveals that you can do

```
hg commit foo.c
```

if you just want to commit a single file. This is just like Subversion and many other systems — no hocus-pocus :-)

Comment: I receive a message "abort ... file not tracked!". My local repository is already tracked by Mercurial. What could be wrong?

Comment: @WindRider: it means that you need to tell Mercurial that you want to track the file first. Use [`hg add` for that](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#add). See also [a Mercurial guide](http://mercurial.aragost.com/kick-start/en/basic/#creating-a-changeset)

Answer (score 7):

Just do:

```
hg ci -I path/to/file -m "commited only one file"
```

That commits only one file, and you can push it, and none of the uncommitted changes will be affected.

Comment: you should also be able to do it just like you would in svn: hg commit -m "here is my message" path/to/file

Answer (score 2):

On the off chance you're running on Windows, [TortoiseHG](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/) (a graphical Mercurial interface) lets you select which files to commit every time.