# Exclude file from a changeset?

Tags: version-control, mercurial, commit, dvcs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using mercurial, what's the easiest way to commit and push a single file while leaving other modifications alone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125272/using-mercurial-whats-the-easiest-way-to-commit-and-push-a-single-file-while-l)
>   [Check in single file with Mercurial?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2908102/check-in-single-file-with-mercurial)

I made changes to 2 files. One has a bug fix, the other has a bunch of temporary debugging code that I want to keep in my working directory for now but do not want to commit.

With git I would only add the first file to the changeset, how do I easiest do this with mercurial?

Comment: Sort of, the question you link to is bigger and more confusing — it talks about pushing and merging too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you not simply commit the one file that you do want:

```
hg commit filename
```

Alternatively, you could use the `-X` option to exlude the other file:

```
hg commit -X filename2
```

Since you only have 2 files, one which should be commited and one which should not, it doesn't really make a difference either way.

See the [documentation](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#commit) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

Just use

```
$ hg commit your-file
```

You might also find the [record extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/RecordExtension) interesting: it let's you commit only *part* of the changes made in a file.